# Ubuntu on Windows 10 has 100% CPU usage with "init" processes

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cpu-load

After first running the Ubuntu app (downloaded from Windows Store),
the *init* processes can't be ended by closing the app or by the Task Manager. Reinstalling didn't help to solve the problem.

Maybe there's another recommended app for shell? What can I do to fix it?

100% CPU usage:

[image: 100% CPU usage]

System info:

[image: System info]

Comment: I found the solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215167/windows-10-ubuntu-wsl-freezes-randomly It's very easy to solve the issue :)

Comment: user1051807, thanks a lot! now Ubuntu works without any troubles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I experienced a similar issue with bash (unkillable bash and init process eating CPU until hard reset). I solved it enabling windows 10 virtual machine platform [(step by step tutorial)](https://teckangaroo.com/enable-windows-10-virtual-machine-platform/) as advised in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215167/windows-10-ubuntu-wsl-freezes-randomly).

It seems to work like a charm now.

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Reinstalled windows subsystem for linux and that solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks. After third reinstalling subsystem for Linux, Ubuntu work a bit. But, there are still same troubles:
1. It's impossible to finish app correctly, _init_ or _bash_ processes remain running, and there a no way to kill it. I tried with task manager, command prompt, power shell - not working.
2. Ubuntu working until some command (like _ls_ or _mkdir_ or anything else) just puts Ubuntu in "not responding" state. As previous described, with 100% CPU usage. 

So,I have to restart PC every 10-20 minutes when Ubuntu is working. Still looking for solution to finish app correctly at least.